# Merge Threads in a Multi-threaded Merge Sort (c)

Tags: c, multithreading, merge

So I am currently working on a threaded merge sort program. I know my algorithm is correct since it works for a single thread. It is designed such that I have a MergeSort() function which recursively halves an array on both the left and right sides and then I call a Merge() function which does the actual sorting and merging. So for my multi-threaded merge-sort, I am partitioning my array in main according to the number of threads passed in (on the command line) and then sending each thread to my MergeSort() function. So far, my program is able to send each sub-array to MergeSort and sort the individual chunks within each thread. My problem now is calling a final merge on all threads. Am I supposed to thread the master merge at the end? Or can I just call Merge on whole array at once (from 0 to N-1)? How should I think about approaching this problem? Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is good, but can you please add the code so we can play with it ?
You are absolutely correct the final array is not sorted but only the chunks. What you can do is call merge sort on the whole array. But don't split until there's only one element in array... stop once each sub array of size `N/number of threads` assuming N is a power of 2 and number of threads as well.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].